# WPF nested ListBox control does not update the list it is bound to

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, listbox

I have the following two classes (with altered names), that will be used to populate a ListView with a nested Listbox

```
private class ObjectName //For the Listview
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public List<BabyObject> Field3 { get; set; }
}

private class BabyObject //For the nested Listbox
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public bool Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

I populate an Observable Collection with some objects and set it as the ItemsSource of my ListView.

My ListView correctly displays the Objects in each ListViewItem, and the nested listbox in each item correctly displays each BabyObject.

**The Problem:**
If I edit the ID, Field1 or Field2 values using the UI, the Observable Collection in memory also updates - of course it does, because of the binding. However if I edit any of the BabyObject's values, the List in memory doesn't change.

Therefore, when I change the Controltemplate of the ListView (so that values are displayed in labels instead of textboxes), the BabyObject values change back to their original.

I know people often have trouble updating the interface when Lists are updated in code, but not this way round?

I'll be happy to answer questions and include more code but the XAML is rather large. In the meantime I am going to make a separate example listview to see if I can test this on a smaller control.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have a `Binding` error? Can you show how you have data bound your `BabyObject` properties please?

Comment: If you did not repeat filed names it would be easier to follow.  If BabyObject is not updating then you don't have binding properly configured.  Show your XAML.  Really you see get called on BabyObject but not set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise a property change notification when the properties are set - this tells the bindings to update.

[MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I will give this a try - but why do I **not** need to do this for the ObjactName class?

Comment: Because an ObservableCollection is WPF "Aware"

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. I am not trying to tell the interface that my collection has updated. I am trying to make my collection update!

Comment: @Robert Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve please.  When you say your collection doesn't update what do you mean?  If you mean the list of BabyObjects isn't updated on screen when you add a new one then perhaps try changing the `List<BabyObject>` inside `ObjectName` to be an `ObservableCollection<BabyObject>`

Comment: I mean when I edit the values of BabyObjects using the interface, my List doesn't update. I'll consider editing the question.

Comment: @Robert What evidence do you have the collection is not updating. If your set is not being called it is because binding it not correct.  Another UI reference will not update unless you NPC.

Comment: @Robert - how are you updating the values?  Is the binding correct on your templates - can you provide the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, however I have no idea what was causing it.

I tried setting the Binding of the Baby Objects to a variety of Modes, and changed the List to an Observable Collection.

This did not work, so I manually undone the changes (Not setting the mode and using a List) - and now it works fine.

If I edit the BabyObject values using the interface, the changes are also made to the List.

I am baffled too - sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: That is not an answer that is going to help anyone.  I suggest you delete the question.

Comment: I agree - I flagged the question for a moderator